# Clipping Mask doesn't work with Artboard in PS CC 2015.1.2. How to enable?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, clipping-mask

So I have this set up. And the image have to be behind `Rectangle 1` but over background `Layer 1`. But for some reason it is not. How to make it work as expected?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the layers upside down.

The the image should go above the shape layer. Then right click the image layer and choose `Clipping Mask`.

[image: Screen shot of clipping mask]

Another way to do this is to set your Rectangle tool options to `Path`. Then hit the `Mask` button in the tool options. This will apply a vector mask directly to the image layer.

[image: Screen shot applying path as vector mask]